# Qt 5: Access Cookies in QtWebEngine

Tags: c++, qt, cookies, qtnetwork, qtwebengine

Is it possible to access the `QNetworkCookieJar` in `QtWebEngine` like you could before with `QtWebKit`? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430864/how-to-set-qnetworkcookiejar-in-qwebengine/38351551#38351551

Answer (score 3):

From Qt 5.6 onwards you can use the [QWebEngineCookieStore class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginecookiestore.html).

Comment: That link doesn't work, try https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qwebenginecookiestore.html

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I now fixed it to point to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[QNetworkCookie](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qnetworkcookie.html) is available for QtWebEngine, but only through the old `QNetworkAccessManager` as `QtWebEngine` is using its own HTTP implementation. You can notice this [while reading one of the examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-browser-browser-pro.html):

```
contains(DEFINES, QWEBENGINEPAGE_SETNETWORKACCESSMANAGER) {
    HEADERS += cookiejar.h networkaccessmanager.h
    SOURCES += cookiejar.cpp networkaccessmanager.cpp
}
```

Please refer to the following example for details:

[WebEngine Tab Browser Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-browser-example.html)

Comment: I expect this to improve in the future, however, as it feels like a nasty workaround. After all, it is a quite new module.

Comment: The link to the WebEngine Tab Browser Example doesn't work anymore. There are four examples on http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/webengine-widgetexamples.html but the tab browser doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: I've looked at the browser example in Qt 5.5.1 and the flag QWEBENGINEPAGE_SETNETWORKACCESSMANAGER doesn't work. It requires the function QWebPage::setNetworkAccessManager() which isn't supported in Qt5. I can't see any way of doing this unless we have Qt5.6.